Using custom generated .dylib in flutter for sqflite_common_ffi iOS
I've added some custom functions into sqlite3.c file and compiled it with /usr/bin/llvm-gcc including the appropriate iPhoneSimulator.sdk for -isysroot.
loaded it with this and it loads fine(added customsqlite.dylib to Runner.xcworkspace):
open.overrideForAll(_openOnIOS);
DynamicLibrary _openOnIOS() {
  return DynamicLibrary.open('customsqlite.dylib');
}

but sqflite_common_ffi still ignores it.
How can I make sqflite_common_ffi to use customsqlite.dylib for iOS, or should I use other ffi bindings similar to sqflite_common_ffi for custom library?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
